# Funcão javascript em string html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um loop que exibe varias divs,e tenho um span que tem uma função chamada remove, no entanto quando click para executar a função sempre da erro mas no html ela está correta.

```js
(function() {
        //Seta valores padrões
        document.querySelector('[data-js="pageTitle"]').innerHTML = datasource[0].pageName;
        document.querySelector('[data-js="title"]').innerHTML = datasource[0].title;
        document.querySelector('[data-js="subtitle"]').innerHTML = datasource[0].subtitle;
        document.querySelector('[data-js="logo"]').src = "./images/"+datasource[0].logo;

        localStorage.defaultData = JSON.stringify(datasource[0].data)

        if(localStorage.default === 'true'){
          var info = _getObject({key:'defaultData', typeResponse:'object'});
        }else{
          var info = _getObject({key:'links', typeResponse:'object'});
        }

        var el = document.querySelector('[data-js=items]');
        var elDef  = "<a href='#openModal' class='blocks blocks__default'>+</a>";
        var cnt = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        cnt += "<span class='remove' onclick='remover("+info[i].id+")'>x</span>";
        cnt += "<a href="+info[i].link+" id="+info[i].id+" target='_blank'>";
        cnt += "<div class='blocks' title="+info[i].description+">";
        cnt += "<h5>"+info[i].title+"</h5>";
        cnt += "<img src='./images/"+ info[i].logo +"' alt='RH web'>";
        cnt += "</div>";
        cnt += "</a>";
        }
        cnt += elDef;
        el.innerHTML = cnt;
      })();

function remover(id){
        console.log(id);
      }
```

No html ela aparece certinho

```
<span class="remove" onclick="remover(301ec16263120ee1a113a5)">x</span>
```

Mas quando click para executar sempre retorna erro.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Podes dar exemplo de um desses `info[i].id`? é um numero ou uma palavra?

Comment: Amigo onde você cria a variável 'datasource' ?

Comment: `info[i].id` uma string formada por letras e numeros.
`datasource` é um arquivo chamado externamente que possui um objeto.

@fsola era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe o parâmetro com aspas para a função.

Substitua:

```
cnt += "<span class='remove' onclick='remover("+info[i].id+")'>x</span>";
```

Por:

```
cnt += "<span class='remove' onclick='remover(\""+info[i].id+"\")'>x</span>";
```

O resultado final deverá ser:

```
<span class="remove" onclick='remover("301ec16263120ee1a113a5")'>x</span>
```

Comment: era isso mesmo obrigado.